# Python Error: NameError: global name 'playerChoice' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game, but I always get the error specified in the title. This is the code. The error pops up about line 21. I am a beginner so please keep it relatively simple.

```
import random

def displayIntro():
print('Hello! This a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors, against the computer.')
print()

def humanChoice():
playerChoice = ''
while playerChoice != 'Rock' and playerChoice != 'Paper' and playerChoice != 'Scissors':
    print('Please choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors. BTW: Please type your choice with the first letter as a capital.')
    playerChoice = input()

return playerChoice

a = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

def computerChoice():
    compChoice = random.choice(a)

def winner():
    if playerChoice == compChoice:
        print('You tied! The computer also chose ' + playerChoice)

    elif playerChoice == Rock and compChoice == Scissors:
    print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' +compChoice)

    elif playerChoice == Paper and compChoice == Rock:
    print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' +compChoice)

    elif playerChoice == Scissors and compChoice == Paper:
    print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' +compChoice)

    else:
    print('You lost! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' +compChoice)

playAgain = 'yes'

while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'Yes':

    displayIntro()

    humanChoice()

    computerChoice()

    winner()

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Comment: Traceback would be nice. Proper indentation too.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems in the code:

- indentation
- undefined `playerChoice`, `compChoice`, `Rock`, `Paper`, `Scissors` variables
- the code "smells" bad, it's not aware of [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide (sorry, it may sound a bit rude, I undestand that you are learning python)
- no `return` in `computerChoice()` function

The main problem, though, is in undefined variables. Instead of using global variables, you should pass the result of `humanChoice()` and `computerChoice()` functions to the `winner()` function. Also, you should make `Rock`, `Paper`, `Scissors` strings.

Here's the code with modifications:

```
import random


def displayIntro():
    print('Hello! This a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors, against the computer.')
    print()


def humanChoice():
    playerChoice = ''
    while playerChoice != 'Rock' and playerChoice != 'Paper' and playerChoice != 'Scissors':
        print('Please choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors. BTW: Please type your choice with the first letter as a capital.')
        playerChoice = input()

    return playerChoice


def computerChoice():
    return random.choice(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"])


def winner(playerChoice, compChoice):
    if playerChoice == compChoice:
        print('You tied! The computer also chose ' + playerChoice)

    elif playerChoice == 'Rock' and compChoice == 'Scissors':
        print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' + compChoice)

    elif playerChoice == 'Paper' and compChoice == 'Rock':
        print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' + compChoice)

    elif playerChoice == 'Scissors' and compChoice == 'Paper':
        print('You won! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' + compChoice)

    else:
        print('You lost! You chose ' + playerChoice + ' and the computer chose ' + compChoice)


playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain in ('yes', 'Yes'):
    displayIntro()
    playerChoice = humanChoice()
    compChoice = computerChoice()
    winner(playerChoice, compChoice)

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify playerChoice, you need to declare it as global in the function and declare it above the first place you want to use it:

```
playerChoice = ''

def humanChoice():
    global playerChoice
    playerChoice = '...'
```

Note that this is not a great programming strategy since it uses global variables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).

Comment: That seems to work, but then it highlights the = and says "invalid syntax".

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it outside of the function:

```
playerChoice = ''
def humanChoice():
```

wish it helps